# How to get all the dates in a full calendar month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calendar

In a calendar control, we can see some dates from the previous month and next month also. Sample image below

[image]

```
(ie Apr-2016: Starts from Mar-28 and ends in May-08
Mar-2016: Starts from Apr Feb-29 and ends in Apr-10)
```

Here, i need to generate a list of all the dates in a calendar control for a particular year month. My week start is **Monday**.
Here is the tsql script i have tried so far.

```
DECLARE @V_DATE DATE = GETDATE()

;WITH CTE_DATE AS (
        SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE) CDATE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE)
        FROM    CTE_DATE
        WHERE   DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE) <= DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_DATE
```

Result Is:

```
2016-04-01
2016-04-02
.
.
2016-04-29
2016-04-30
```

It will list all the days from a inputted year month, but i need to include the
missing dates from the previous month as well as next month.

Expected result for `Apr-2016`

```
2016-03-28
2016-03-29
.
2016-04-15
.
2016-05-07
2016-05-08
```

Expected result for `May-2016`

```
2016-04-25
2016-04-26
.
2016-05-15
.
2016-06-04
2016-06-05
```

Note:- The calendar control is always showing 42 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your week is starts on Monday,you can take referece to date 0 '1900-01-01' which is a Monday. Adding 41 days would gives you your end date

```
select  
      date_fr = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, '2016-05-01') / 7 * 7, 0),
      date_to = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, '2016-05-01') / 7 * 7, 41)
```

the following gives you date 1900-01-01 and Monday

```
select  convert(datetime, 0), datename(weekday, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a dates table in your database. You would have columns for dates and a column for week number. Linking to this table you could find the week number for your start and end dates, you could then re-link to the table to find the first date of your start week and the last date of your end week. This would probably be more efficient than calculations at each step each time, it is a simple link.

Comment: You could even have (amongst other columns) 'Date', 'WeekNum', 'WeekStartDate', 'WeekEndDate'. That would require only the one link to the table then.

Answer (score 0):

I have create done script for this. This is working as per my expectation, may be helpful for future reference. (Thanks @Squirrel for the logic).

```
DECLARE @V_ST_DATE  DATE = GETDATE()

SET @V_ST_DATE  =   DATEADD(DAY,-(DAY(@V_ST_DATE)-1),@V_ST_DATE)

SET @V_ST_DATE  =   DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @V_ST_DATE) ,0) + 
        (CASE WHEN DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @V_ST_DATE) ,0) > @V_ST_DATE THEN -7 ELSE 0 END)

;WITH CTE_DATE AS (
        SELECT  @V_ST_DATE CDATE,0 TDAYS
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE) , DATEDIFF(DAY,@V_ST_DATE, DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE))
        FROM    CTE_DATE
        WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY,@V_ST_DATE, DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)) < 42
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_DATE
```